# What is the correct way to write chainable function in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I try to write custom function for my Angular app.
I have followed official guide and create an independent library.

I intent to write chainable function like this

```
var obj = {
  test : function(){ 
    console.log('1'); 
    return this; 
  },
  test2 : function(){ 
    console.log('2'); 
    return this; 
  }
}
obj.test().test2();
```

How to export and import a chainable method in Angular? And which is the correct file type that I should write this custom function? For example, might be service, model, or component?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to export and import a chainable method in Angular

If you care about inferred type safety use a class:

```
class Obj {
    test() {
        console.log(1);
        return this;
    }
    test2() {
        console.log(2);
        return this;
    }
}

new Obj().test().test2();
```

> And which is the correct file type that I should write this custom function? For example, might be service, model, or component?

In any `.ts` file. Simply export e.g.:

```
export const obj = new Obj();
```

Comment: Thanks basarat. I have achieved the goal by this way.

Answer (score 0):

**Library: Underscore.js**

If you're willing to use a (small) library, Underscore.js provides a [chain()](https://underscorejs.org/#chain) methods that lets you chain calls together and return the result. To use or add a custom function, you could create a *mixin* which is basically your own custom underscore function.

As an example - take some JSON, map it, and apply a custom function to the items then show something:

**example code**

```
_.mixin({
  test_logging: function(stuff) {
    console.log(" * test()!");
    console.log({'stuff': stuff});
    return stuff;
  },
  test_message: function(stuff) {
    return JSON.stringify(stuff);
  }
});

var results = _.chain(data)
                .map(function(user) {
                    return {
                    'name': user.name,
                    'email': user.email,
                    'company': user.company
                  };
                })
                .test_logging()
                .test_message()
                .value();
```

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/182026/)